# Avoid needing to import modules multiple times

Tags: python, file, import, directory, nameerror

So I want to split up my code in bitsizechunks. This is done by putting them in separate files. However when I go to import a function form such file. This needs separate imports. How can I avoid this? Beneath I put a simple example to illustrate my point.

say this is help.py:

```
def funcPi():
    return np.pi
```

and this is main.py

```
import numpy as np
from help import funcPi
def main():
    print(funcPi())
main()
```

This would result in the error :

```
NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

How do I fix this without having to import numpy in the help.py file?

Comment: Why don't you want to import numpy in help.py?

Comment: This is a simple example, but I would need to load a lot of sub-modules in separate files into each .py file and this becomes a mess. Plus I was wondering if it is possible.